# Extract unique combinations from Excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba, unique

I am looking for a way to extract all unique combinations from a number of Excel sheets with multiple columns. E.g.:

```
#no.   | fruit    | city    | year    | something else
1      | apple    | London  | 2015    | some text
2      | banana   | London  | 1999    | no text
3      | apple    | Oxford  | 1895    | some text
4      | banana   | London  | 1999    | no text
```

How can I get a list of all unique rows (except for column 1 of course) with any function in Excel or VBA? Preferably it is a script-like way, because the sheets contain over 6000 rows of varying information.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use Remove Duplicates, it is located under the data tab.

Comment: @ScottCraner is right, i tried coding but easiest option is remove duplicated, copy the unique values elswhere and then be sure not to save changes in the original workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to do it with just formulas, here is some simple steps:

1) Add column at the end of table. In this column, concenate all rows like this:

```
#no.   | fruit    | city    | year    | something else|
1      | apple    | London  | 2015    | some text     |=B2&C2&D2&E2
2      | banana   | London  | 1999    | no text       |
3      | apple    | Oxford  | 1895    | some text     |
4      | banana   | London  | 1999    | no text       |
```

2) Then add another column to count and numerate occurences of dublicates. Put `COUNTIF()` formula and fill down:

```
no     | fruit    | city    | year    | something else|  Column F  |
1      | apple    | London  | 2015    | some text     |=B2&C2&D2&E2|=COUNTIF($F$2:F2,F2)
2      | banana   | London  | 1999    | no text       |
3      | apple    | Oxford  | 1895    | some text     |
4      | banana   | London  | 1999    | no text       |
```

If you filter last column with **criteria=1** you can get all unique rows.